# C# TCPClient, BeginRead eventually results in callback-spam

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I'm currently using the C# TcpClient/TcpListener classes to send and receive data on both ends, but a weird issue keeps coming up that's really starting to bug me:

In a debug environment (local) everything works fine over several hours, days, ... however in the live environment where the software is supposed to be used in, after several minutes/hours some clients randomy decide to spam the incoming stream with empty packages. The code I'm using to read from it is BeginRead as shown below:

```
tcpClient.GetStream().BeginRead(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length, new AsyncCallback(MessageReceivedNew), tcpClient.GetStream());
```

This works absolutely fine for most clients over days, however some of them randomly start calling the callback "MessageReceivedNew" hundreds of times per second after a few minutes/hours of running just fine. The issue persists even after blocking those clients in the firewall until the application has been fully closed or the tcp client has been disconnected. The buffer always stays empty (works fine before the random spam starts).

The code I'm using in the callback to handle the messages is

```
int bytesRead = 0;

try {
    NetworkStream ns = tcpClient.GetStream();
    bytesRead = ns.EndRead(ar);
    IsListening = false;
} catch (Exception ex) {
    if (ex is IOException || ex is ObjectDisposedException) {
        OnNetworkStreamException.Invoke(this);
    } else {
        OnUnexpectedError.Invoke(this, ex);
    }

    if (!IsExpectedToDisconnect) SocketExceptionCloseConnection();
    OnClientDisconnected.Invoke(this, DisconnectType);
    return;
}

...message processing...

Receive();
```

Comment: Try not to access TcpClient in your callback. Especially don't call GetStream again. Instead, pass the original stream in a data object as demonstrated in the Microsoft samples. Whether that causes your problems - not sure, but the other way is the recommended way of imolemenring asynchonous communication.

Comment: The connection is probably being closed due to inactivity.  The code when the connection breaks must be attempting to make new connection before first connection completely closes.  I would use from cmd.exe >NetStat -a to get status of connection at both client and server when issue occurs.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Just changed that and test it now. Would you recommend passing that NetworkStream object directly back to the BeginRead method or fetch the stream via GetStream() after processing a message?

Comment: @jdweng I've implemented a keepalive that goes both ways so I assume it's not due to inactivity. The issue only occurs on the server and not the clients, sending to the clients works fine but the server goes crazy, it's really weird.

Comment: How much data are you sending.  Some server have limits around ~10M to 20M.

Comment: I think that you should always use the original instance of the stream. I'm not sure what happens when you call the method more than once.

Comment: @jdweng Keepalive packages are about 5 bytes, normal messages usually go up to 250 bytes but with larger intervals.

Comment: Ryan : Wrong.  You probably are including the IP Header and TCP header.   A keep-alive has the IP and TCP headers, but the data portion is zero bytes.  TCP can have a maximum byte size of ~1500 Bytes.  When messages are longs there are bits in the header that indicate the message is a continuation packets.